# i want to add messageBoxIcons onto pictureBox Image

Tags: c#

I want to add `messageBoxIcons` onto `pictureBox` Image.
I tried with Bitmap but did not work.
`pictureBox1.Image = new Icon(MessageBoxIcon.Error.ToString(), new Size(40, 40)).ToBitmap();`

Comment: `new Bitmap(SystemIcons.Error.ToBitmap(), new Size(40, 40))`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.